# Is it possible to create google app engine web application with default google page template?

Tags: google-app-engine

"default google page template" means a page with design like in google groups, for example. Some standard google header in top, sidebar with menu in the left of a page and central section with content https://groups.google.com/forum ?
"Create Application" -> "Use standard template" -> ...

Comment: What language are you using? App Engine supports many languages.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in template that you can use. You can create it yourself, of courese